# How can I find accented letters in a string using go?

Tags: go, utf-8

#### Given a string *var word* that represents a word, and a string *var letter* that represents a letter, how do I count the number of accented letters in the word?

If *var letter* is a non-accented word, my code works, but when the letter is accented or any special character, *var counter* prints the number 0.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    word := "cèòài"
    letter := "è"
    var counter int

    for i := 0; i < len(word); i++ {
        if string(word[i]) == letter {
            counter++
        }
    }
    fmt.Print(counter)
}
```

I imagine this error is due to some encoding problem but can't quite grasp what I need to look into.

Comment: You are indexing individual bytes from the `word` string, but `letter` is multiple bytes itself, so they could never match. Maybe read: https://go.dev/blog/strings

Comment: What, if anything, would you like to do about decomposed vs composed accents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about utilizing [`strings.Count`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Count):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    word := "cèòài"
    letter := "è"
    letterOccurences := strings.Count(word, letter)
    fmt.Printf("No. of occurences of \"%s\" in \"%s\": %d\n", letter, word, letterOccurences)
}
```

**Output:**

```
No. of occurences of "è" in "cèòài": 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JimB alluded to, letters (aka runes) in a string may not be at exactly matching byte-offsets:

To iterate a string over its individual runes:

```
for pos, l := range word {
    _ = pos // byte position e.g. 3rd rune may be at byte-position 6 because of multi-byte runes

    if string(l) == letter {
        counter++
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/wZOIEedf-ee